# Disable images on Google Reader

Tags: google-reader, images

How do I disable images in feeds on Google Reader?

I am open to using browser extensions and URL hacks but not alternatives to Google Reader itself.

Disabling images across the browser isn't acceptable either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a filter to the AdBlock extension.

Install AdBlock and add this filter rule:

`google.com##DIV[class="item-body"] IMG`

[image]

Comment: I was using the Decreased productivity extension from https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nlbpiflhmdcklcbihngeffpmoklbiooj Guess this is better. Thanks...